# Dependent junit tests for mybatis mappers

Tags: java, junit, mybatis

I am currently using mybatis for CRUD operations to a database for a web service, configured via xml mapper files. In previous efforts, to test our mappers we would write a unit test for each method on the mapper, so for a select we would write some boilerplate to create an entity and insert it into an in memory database, then we would call our mapper to retrieve it and do some assertions on what we got back. This applies for other CRUD tests(for insert, create and insert the entity via the mapper, write a simple query to retrieve the just inserted data and assert, or check the database row count etc).

I've also been reading up on the idea of unit tests that depend on each other(run testB only if testA passes, assume the rowCount is greater than 0 before performing the select test etc) I've seen some debate on whether these truly count as unit tests or if they are more integration tests.

What I want to know is, for mybatis mappers, is it worth creating a isolated test for each function, and just putting up with the extra code needed to get the database into a state suitable for the test, or to retrieve inserted data etc. Or does it make more sense to introduce this test dependency mechanism and treat it as more of an integration test(if the insert fails, dont bother with the select and so on)?

To add a little more perspective, currently we have the standard unit tests for the mappers, then above that are the integration tests with a service(create an entity to save from json, save it, retrieve and convert to another object to be sent to another service, things of this nature). Im not sure how to define the dependent junits; to me they seem like they would sit between the unit test layer and the integration test layer above

Comment: This question may be somewhat broad, but I've thrown this idea around my team and they aren't overly concerned with either approach; I just want to know which would be a more sensible approach for mybatis testing

Comment: Does anyone have an opinion on this?